# Highlight datatable row whenever there's a change in the data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using datatables to display some data. And I'm updating the rows using the table.ajax.reload.

What I'd like to do is to highlight rows that get changed. highlight green when the last column goes up. and highlight red when the last column goes down.

Does the datatables api have built in way to do this?

```
<table id="example1" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
        <tr><th>Coin</th><th>last</th><th>lowestAsk</th><th>highestBid</th><th>percentChange</th><th>baseVolume</th><th>quoteVolume</th><th>isFrozen</th><th>high24hr</th><th>low24hr</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><th>Coin</th><th>last</th><th>lowestAsk</th><th>highestBid</th><th>percentChange</th><th>baseVolume</th><th>quoteVolume</th><th>isFrozen</th><th>high24hr</th><th>low24hr</th></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>


$(document).ready(function() {
var uriToken = '/dfeed.php';
var table = $('#example1').DataTable( {
    //"processing": true,
    //"serverSide": true,
    //"searching": true,
    "ajax": uriToken + '?get_ticker2=1',
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Coin" },
        { "data": "last" },
        { "data": "lowestAsk" },
        { "data": "highestBid" },
        { "data": "percentChange" },
        { "data": "baseVolume" },
        { "data": "quoteVolume" },
        { "data": "isFrozen" },
        { "data": "high24hr" },
        { "data": "low24hr" }
        ]
} );



window.setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload( null, false ); // user paging is not reset on reload
    //console.log("tick");
}, 3000  } );
```

Comment: you should use the reload callback to compare your 2 sets of data

Comment: cool. how we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Datatable does not attribute any `id` or `class` to all its `<td>`.

So you could try to wrap your updated values with a `span`...
Something like: `<span class="updatedValue">Your value</span>`.

Then via jquery, right after your reload:

```
$(".updatedValue").parent().css({"background-color":"#10E438"});  // Or any other green color number ;)
```